# error: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimary' not found

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Recently I updated my target SDK to 29 as per new Android guidelines but after that I received this error:

> D:\Android Apps\PatherPane\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:4:5-9:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimary (aka com.patherpane.app:attr/colorPrimary)' not found.

And my style XML file is:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="SplashScreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">
        @drawable/background_splashscreen
    </item>
</style>
```

How can I fix this?

This command followed by item names is showing the error: `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Make sure you have not missed **appcompat** implementation in *build.gradle*(app)

```
implementation ‘com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0’
```

or

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
```

if using **androidx**

Answer (score 13):

Had this in a library module, which suddenly stopped resolving the theme.

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0"
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This error commonly shows up when

```
androidx.appcompat:appcompat
```

and

```
com.google.android.material:material
```

versions do not match. Check whether you updated one and not the other. The versions should be the same for both.

Comment: How do you find a table of matching versions? How do you know which compileSdkVersion needs which appcompat?

Answer (score 0):

Go to app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml
It should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>  //This is where the colorPrimary is defined
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
</resources>
```

Make sure that the line that I commented exists, has correct syntax, and defines the appropriate 6-digit hexcode in the middle. The hexcode should be the primary color of the theme you are designing.

Comment: Hello , Thats What I have Already In Colour File , But I was Talking about the Style File